# Difference between max length of word ngrams and size of context window

Tags: python, nlp, fasttext

In the description of the fasttext library for python https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python for training a supervised model there are different arguments, where among others are stated as:

- `ws`: size of the context window
- `wordNgrams`: max length of word ngram.

If I understand it right, both of them are responsible for taking into account the surrounding words of the word, but what is the clear difference between them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, we use the `train_unsupervised` API to create a **Word-Representation Model**. There are two techniques that we can use, [skipgram](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf) and [cbow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf). On the other hand, we use the `train_supervised` API to create **Text Classification Model**. You are asking about the `train_supervised` API, so I will stick to it.

The way that text classification work in fasttext, is to first represent the word using skipgram by default. Then, use these word-vectors learned from the skipgram model to classify your input text. The two parameters that you asked about (`ws` and `wordNgrams`) are related to the skipgram/cbow model.

The following image contains a simplified illustration of how we are using our input text to train skipgram model. Here, we defined the `ws` parameter as 2 and `wordNgrams` as 1.

[image]

As we can see, we have only one text in our training data which is `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`. We defined the context window to be two, which means that we will create a window whose center is `center word` and the next/previous two words within the window are `target words`. Then, we move this window a word at a time. The bigger the window size is, the more training samples you have for your model, the more overfitted the model becomes given a small sample of data.

That's for our first argument `ws`. According to the second argument `wordNgrams`, if we set `wordNgrams` to 2, it will consider two-word pairs like the following image. (The `ws` in the following image is one for simplicity)

[image]

### Ref

- Check this [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/FastText.py) which contains the source code for the `train_supervised` method.
- There is a major difference between skipgram and cbow that can be summarized in the following image:

[image: skipgram vs. cbow]

Comment: Thanks a lot! An amazing explanation.