# Fast Text unsupervised model loss

Tags: word-embedding, fasttext

I wanted to create a fastText unsupervised model for my text data of size 1GB. I'm using fastText command line tool to implement the model training process.

```
./fasttext skipgram -input PlainText.txt -output FastText-PlainText- -dim 50 -epoch 50
```

The above are few arguments I used for created word representation.

```
Read 207M words
Number of words:  501986
Number of labels: 0
Progress:  97.5% words/sec/thread:   87224 lr:  0.001260 avg.loss:  0.089536 ETA:   0h 4m 9s
```

Here, in the output of the fastText command, I see this avg.loss and the learning rate has been decreased from default (0.5) to 0.001. I don't really understand, what does this avg.loss mean and why is the learning rate is dropped?

1. Should I want to increase the epoch to make fastText to learn my data better?
2. Can I use any loss function to improve the loss? If yes, what kind of loss function will be better?
3. And how can I evaluate my fastText model's learning whether is good or bad?
4. Just out of interest, Can I use wordngrams to make my model learn better with context in unsupervised learning?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer all your questions in depth, but I try to give you some advice.

- you can understand better *avg.loss*, reading [this thread](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/690#issuecomment-441570351)
- learning rate is updated according *lrUpdateRate* option (read [this](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html)).
- in general, increasing the number of epochs can improve learning. However, as you can read in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06669.pdf), the most popular language models have a number of epochs between 10 and 100.
- default loss function is softmax. You can also choose hs (hierarchical softmax) or ns. You can read more in the [official tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#advanced-readers-hierarchical-softmax).
- if you want to learn more about the effects of the *ws* and *wordngrams* parameters, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507056/difference-between-max-length-of-word-ngrams-and-size-of-context-window).